# The public keys from iOS developer profile not transfered to another machine. Bug or they are never needed again?

Tags: xcode, certificate, keychain

I have two dev machines I want to use for iOS development.

I have successfully setup my iOS dev profile on my main machine. I can see in Keychain Access app that I have two pairs of keys: iOS Developer public & private keys and iOS Distribution public and private keys.

I transferred my iOS developer profile to a secondary machine using procedure described at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/080-Manage_Your_Devices/manage_devices.html (section "Transfer Your Developer Profile to Another Computer"). All went fine and I am able to deploy to my devices.

I have noticed in Keychain Access app that **the secondary machine doesn't contain my public keys**, only private keys and certs are present. The public keys were not transferred.

If I am going to be a team member and I'd like to ask the team admin for a cert doesn't it involve my public keys? If it does people who just followed Apple's instructions will not have those public keys.

I have managed to move the public keys manually, this is not a problem but I want to understand why public keys are not included in the dev profile transfer procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The public key is used to generate the certificate. Then, the private key is used to verify the certificate and the provisioning profile that includes it. When you request a new certificate, another pair of keys will be created. Probably, the public key is not transfered during the transfer process because it's not more useful. Here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/10-Configuring_Development_and_Distribution_Assets/identities_and_devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW3 you can find some more detail.